# Is there any standard format for the title page of a manuscript?

Tags: publishing, first-time-author, manuscripts

I'm finally ready to send my manuscript to the publisher. I'm wondering if there is any standard way to format the title page of the document. I'm including such details as my name, the working title, date of the draft, all of my contact information. Is there a standard accepted practice for arranging this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you know about the William Shunn Manuscript Format site? Here is the link:

https://www.shunn.net/format/novel/

There are pages for novel and short story formatting. As you probably guessed, the link in this answer takes you to the novel page. I don't bother with the "he/him" identification. That's only a personal preference, not any kind of statement or judgment.

As someone told me many years ago, "manuscript format is like wearing your best business attire to a job interview."

Comment: The most important rule is that if you're asked to provide certain information on a cover page, be sure to provide it. Likewise, if you're specifically asked to provide a cover page but your writing book says "you don't need a cover page for XXX", provide a cover page. Likewise for page headings, footers, and other elements. Some publication have submission guidelines which go into what seems absurd detail about what they like, but a general website like Shunn's is useful if there is no specific guidance. How To Write books always claim "follow my rule or be rejected" but often that's nonsense